# Can I use hyphens in a path with 'use' keyword in PHP?

Tags: php, paypal, composer-php

I am trying to implement PayPal checkout integration in a project. For that I used composer to install paypal-checkout-sdk v1.0.0. And now when I am trying to use the `use` keyword, it is giving me an syntax error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how can I find a work around for this issue?

I have tried using single as well as double quotes with the path.

```
use vendor\paypal\paypal-checkout-sdk\lib\PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
```

After running the application and accessing it from browser I get following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: You would use the namespace, not the file path. The file path would go in the autoloader.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you have to provide the **FQCN** (fully-qualified class name) to a `use` statement **not** the path inside composer's vendor-directory.

This is the correct use-statement for the `PayPalHttpClient` class:

```
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
```